# A linear map of determinant $1$ cannot decrease the length of all of the vectors in a Parseval frame

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $u_1,...,u_k$ be unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, with $k \geq n$, such that there exist scalars $c_1,...,c_k$ so that, for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$,
$$\sum\limits_i c_i \langle x , u_i \rangle^2 = |x|^2,$$
or equivalently
$$\sum\limits_i c_i \langle x , u_i \rangle u_i = x$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. This is the same as saying that the vectors $\sqrt{c_i}u_i$ form a Parseval frame. In [these notes by Ball](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf), it is asserted that this implies that if $T$ is a linear map of determinant $1$, then for at least one $i$, $|T u_i| \geq 1$. Is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: The idea is the following: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.  Since the determinant is $1$, at least one of the eigenvalues is greater than $1$.  Let $u$ be the corresponding eigenvector.  Write $u$ as a sum of the $u_i$'s and see what happens if they all shrink.

Comment: I was never able to figure this out. In particular, I do not understand the above comment. It seems to me that, if this strategy were to work, we ought to be able to prove this if we relax the requirement that $det(T)=1$ to $T$ merely having an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| \geq 1$. But this is clearly false, as seen by taking, e.g., $n=2$, $c_1 = c_2 = 1$, $u_1 = {\sqrt{2} \over 2} (1,1)$, $u_2 = {\sqrt{2} \over 2} (1,-1)$, and $T : (x,y) \mapsto (x,0)$.

Comment: Where in the notes is this assertion?

Comment: The first full paragraph on page 16.

Comment: Your example has determinant $0$, not $1$.  The corresponding matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Observe also that the scalars are positive in the notes.

Comment: Yes I agree that the determinant is $0$. What I don't understand about your comment is that it seems to imply that all we need is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| \geq 1$, but perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $\sum_ic_i\langle x,u_i\rangle u_i=x$ for all $x$ can be expressed in matrix form as
$$
\sum_ic_i u_iu_i^t=I_n
$$
with $u^t$ representing the transpose of $u$ and $I_n$ is the identity matrix. As $uu^t$ has trace $\lVert u\rVert^2$, we can take the trace of the above expression,
$$
\sum_ic_i\lVert u_i\rVert^2=n.\qquad{\rm(1)}
$$
For an $n\times n$ matrix $T$,
$$
\sum_ic_i(Tu_i)(Tu_i)^t=TT^t
$$
and, taking the trace again,
$$
\sum_ic_i\lVert Tu_i\rVert^2={\rm tr}(TT^t).
$$
The symmetric matrix $TT^t$ has nonnegative eigenvalues summing to its trace and whose product is ${\rm det}(T)^2$. By the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),
$$
\sum_ic_i\lVert Tu_i\rVert^2\ge n\,\lvert{\rm det}(T)\rvert^{2/n}.\qquad{\rm(2)}
$$
It is assumed that the $c_i$ are nonnegative so, if $T$ has determinant $1$, then it cannot strictly reduce the size of each $u_i$, since (2) would then contradict (1).